# Query in prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, prisma

I need to do a prism query, where my id is the same as the login id, but idk how do I do it, I'm doing it like this, but it filters all titles, and I just need the title of the login that was done now

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/client';

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient();
  const services = await prisma.service.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: 
    },
  })
  return {
    props: {
      services,
    },
  };
}

export default function Home({ services }) {
  const [session] = useSession();

  return (
    <>
      {!session && (
        <>
          Not signed in
          {' '}
          <br />
          <button type="button" onClick={signIn}>Sign In</button>
        </>
      )}
      {session && (
        <>
          Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
          <ul>
            {services.map((service) => (
              <li key={service.id}>{service.title}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

The "service" is my table, and it is linked to the "session" table, both have the id column, and I only need to show the titles of the "service" that are in the id registered in the "session".

does it make sense what I'm saying? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this page](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side). You can use `getSession` from `next-auth` to get the required user session details.